# Conditional Formatting Defined Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub ConditionalFormattingNamedRange()                                     
Dim x As Range, Cell As Range

Set x = Range("AALB_Exposure")

For Each Cell In x
    If Cell.Value > Sheets("Overview").Range("E4").Value Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
Next 
End Sub
```

Background information: This formula makes values in my defined range "AALB_Exposure" colored if they are larger than cell E4 on sheet "Overview". The value of cell E4 is the result of two other cells. Sometimes one of these cells varies. I have more than 20 defined ranges such as "AALB_Exposure", so I prefer to use a module.

Problem: This module makes all values colored. Sometimes there are some blank cells in "AALB_Exposure". I would like to see that this does not occurs. Is this possible?
In addition, this module is static and does not modifies the color of the cells in the defined range as I adjust E4. This happens only after I run the module. Is it possible to ensure that the color of cells adjust immediately depending on varying the values of E4.

Thank you!

----- Edit ------

After the excellent suggestion of Bruce Wayne, I changed my code a little bit.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Sh As Worksheet) 
If Target.Address = "$A$9" Then                    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Dim x As Range, Cell As Range  
Set x = Sh.Range("P1:P150,AD1:AD150,AR1:AR150,BF1:BF150,BT1:BT150,CH1:CH150,CV1:CV150,DJ1:DJ150,DX1:DX150,EL1:EL150")                                                 
For Each Cell In x
If Cell.Value > Sh.Range("A9").Value And Cell.Value <> "" Then
    Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End If
Next
End If  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End sub

As the named range is always the same for each sheet, it is maybe better to address the problem this way? Consequently, I changed Cell E4 that is located on the Overview sheet for a cell that is always on the same location for each sheet. 
However, is this new module correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to run whenever `E4` is changed, you need to put it in a Worksheet Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$4" Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range, Cell As Range

Set x = Range("AALB_Exposure")

For Each Cell In x
    If Cell.Value > Sheets("Overview").Range("E4").Value And Cell.Value <> "" Then ' added `AND` part to check if cell is not blank
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
Next

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Put that in the *Worksheet Module* of the sheet you want to run it on. It will also check to see if the cell is blank or not before adding the color.